# What's different about the first run?

Tags: hades

What's different about the first run? Or is that too large a question?

I'm wondering what the best one would be, in terms of Meta Progression... It seems like Nectar and Gemstones don't appear as Chamber Rewards on the first run? Or is it just not rewards in Tartarus?

Or have I just been astoundingly unlucky, having my only source of just 1 Nectar be Dionysus?

If so, when or where do they start appearing? If Gemstones, perhaps Run 2, and maybe only on skull chambers, if my two data points are right enough.

...

Then there's Boons, with only Athena, Artemis, Ares, and Dionysus seeming to be available for the first run?

I assume there's further differences as well, given what I've read on the Wiki?

[According to a YouTube guide by Pryde](https://youtu.be/cXTIPUfkGR0?t=664), first run Charon shops don't show any of those who haven't been spoken to.

[And speaking of Chambers](https://youtu.be/cXTIPUfkGR0?t=843), Asphodel can have Food as a reward, if things go wrong / right.

Comment: I do remember one special note - normally you are expected to die, but since you have so many restrictions on the first run, it's actually its own speed running category and so the devs adjusted Hades's dialogue to reflect that the player hasn't actually died yet.

Comment: @AndrewFan - Yeah, on that note, I looked for a guide on Speedrun.com for info, but no dice there. ... I did not expect a Youtube Guide to exist, but it does and says at least No Daedelus Hammers, although that might already be on the Wiki? https://youtu.be/cXTIPUfkGR0?t=218

Comment: Related: [*Can the game be beaten on the first run, and is there any special interactions if you do so?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/378021/181240)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this to be a mostly complete tally of the differences of the first run in Hades but I may have missed a few things or gotten a few things wrong, corrections and additions are welcome.

The following quirks of the first run are inherent to the run itself:

- [Only 4 of the gods will provide boons](http://making%20her%20one%20of%20the%20five%20Olympian%20gods%20(the%20other%20four%20being%20Poseidon,%20Hermes,%20Aphrodite%20and%20Zeus)%20who%20will%20not%20appear%20in%20the%20very%20first%20run%20of%20a%20save) (Ares, Artemis, Athena, and Dionysius), the remaining gods (Aphrodite, Demeter, Hermes, Poseidon and Zeus) will not provide boons as room rewards nor in Charon's shops.
- [The first boon is guaranteed to be from Athena](https://youtu.be/cXTIPUfkGR0?t=623) and contain her attack, cast and dash
- No [Wells of Charon](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Well_of_Charon) in chambers (unlocked on run 2) (the ones after boss rooms are still there)
- No [Daedelus Hammers](https://www.speedrun.com/hades/thread/z73xy/1#o4fap) (unlocked on run 3*)
- No [Trial of the Gods](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Trial_of_the_Gods?#Spawning_Conditions) (unlocked on run 4)
- No [Chaos Gates](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Chaos_Gate?so=search#:%7E:text=relevant%20minor%20prophecy.-,Spawning,-Chaos%20Gates%20will) (unlocked on run 5*)
- No [Calls](https://www.speedrun.com/hades/thread/z73xy/1#o4fap) (unlocked on run 6)
- No [NPC chambers](https://www.speedrun.com/hades/thread/z73xy/1#o4fap) (Sisyphus & Bouldy, Eurydice or Patroclus) (unlocked after beating their respective biome boss for the first time)
- [Food may appear as a chamber reward](https://youtu.be/cXTIPUfkGR0?t=835) (This is apparently to replace NPC chambers which cannot occur in the first run)
- [The boss of Tartarus will be Megaera](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Furies#:%7E:text=Initially%20when%20encountered%2C%20only%20Megaera%20will%20oppose%20Zagreus) (the remaining Furies will begin to appear after beating Meg a certain number of times)
- No [Thanatos](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Thanatos?so=search#Encounters) (must first encounter either Alecto or Tisiphone)
- [Charon cannot be robbed](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Charon?so=search#Combat) (unlocked after beating the final boss)

These quirks anecdotally seem to hold based on self-gathered data and a handful of fresh file speed run videos** but otherwise have no source:

- Gemstones (seems to unlock on run 2) and Nectar (seems to unlock on run 3) will never appear as chamber rewards or in shops, blue laurel chambers will only offer Darkness, Chthonic Keys and rarely food
- Survival rooms do not appear (seems to unlock on run 2)

These quirks of the first run are determined by virtue of not starting at the House of Hades and not having gained any artifact currency yet (Chthonic Keys, Darkness, Titan's Blood, etc.)

- Weapon must be the Stygian Blade (Zagreus aspect, no upgrades)
- No Mirror of Night bonuses (50 base HP, 1 dash, no death's defiance, etc.)
- No House Contractor upgrades (no Fountain Chambers, Infernal Troves, Infernal Gates, Fishing, etc.)
- No Keepsakes/Companions (none available by default and 'Keepsake Collection, Regional' that allows switching between biomes is a House Contractor upgrade)
- No Pact of Punishment (must beat final boss or begin game in Hell mode)

This last one is non-gameplay related but is somewhat of a spoiler:

> Hades has different dialogue when you encounter him to account for the fact that his usual dialogue doesn't make sense on the first run

Footnotes

* Personal testing seems to contradict the linked sources, a Daedelus Hammer appears in run 3 not 4 and Chaos Gates first occur in run 5 not 7, maybe those pieces are obsolete due to updates to the game

** Testing consisted of 3 fresh files with 6 runs apiece and 6 fresh file speed run videos from Youtube done between Nov 2020 and Oct 2021

Comment: Nice! ... So, no confirmation that getting two Nectar is impossible on First Run... But I assume there's locks on possible Chamber Rewards otherwise I should've seen in it 10+ First Runs?

Comment: @Malady Not sure, I didn't see anything that suggested when the artifact currencies first show up if they aren't available by default. I can watch some first run clears later to see if nectar ever appears as a room reward.

Comment: Good luck! If you do... I guess I'll Bounty for your effort, because I'm asking a lot already, but getting my core question answered, well, that's worth it! ... Hope you get tons of rep!

Comment: Seems like Gemstones are unlocked in Run 2... Just tried a second run and seeing it...

Comment: @Malady So across 6 fresh file speedruns on Youtube done between Nov 2020 and Oct 2021 (mostly towards the latter) I've tallied 43 Darkness, 23 Chthonic keys, 0 Gemstones and 0 Nectar offered as room rewards (I wasn't tallying shops but I'm pretty sure I never saw gems or nectar). This rather strongly implies gems / nectar aren't in the first run, I also did a bit testing on my own and the earliest I saw nectar was run 3 and the earliest Gemstones were run 5 (I didn't get very far each run though so needs more data XD). I'll make edits as well as do a bit more testing tomorrow

Comment: Thanks! ... Oh, right, do you know how to copy saves and stuff? - https://www.speedrun.com/hades/guide/uj036... Also, the V save is also where Hell Mode selection is stored, so converting from Hell Mode and Normal is easier than such an irrevocable option perhaps should be.

Comment: @Malady I'm not sure what you mean by your comment, I've never tried fiddling with saves or even playing in Hell mode. Until I started some fresh files for testing and data collection I've only ever used 1 save file for Hades

Comment: Well, you got the data anyway, now I'll give you... 50 rep?